# python logging alternatives

Tags: python, logging, notifications

The Python [logging module](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) is cumbersome to use. Is there a more elegant alternative? Integration with desktop notifications would be a plus.

Comment: Looks promising: http://packages.python.org/Logbook

Comment: In what ways do you find the logging module to be cumbersome?  What do you find lacking in its capabilities?

Comment: @NathanDavis well  just to get started you need to write about 6 lines... want to add to stdout too - thats about another 4, if you can get it to work.

Comment: Anyways, for people who are here, just like me, structlog, loguru are two good alternatives

Comment: @InAFlash isn't it weird that there is a library for everything in python BUT logging LOL. There's no single decent one. However, structlog looks quite promissing.

Comment: i mean, why to worry when print("-----> I'm here <-------") works ?

Comment: @InAFlash it sure does... but not so much if you want to send the logs into a database to let another app analze them and send alarms.

Comment: i found loggin so slow , my code became 10 time slower

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can look into [Twiggy](https://github.com/wearpants/twiggy), it's an early stage attempt to build a more pythonic alternative to the logging module.

Comment: seems dead... last commit was over a year ago

Comment: Not dead, but moved.  The documentation is at https://twiggy.readthedocs.org and the development is on Github at https://github.com/wearpants/twiggy/

Comment: As of today it seems not to be available for Python 3.x - and also not in a proper state for 2.x, the github readme says: "master is currently in flux and may be broken."

Comment: @SHernandez: I tried it today on 3.6 and it works fine. Not sure how robust this is but at least the example ran OK.

Answer (score 6):

Checkout [logbook](https://github.com/getlogbook/logbook), it is much nicer to work with.

Logbook was mentioned in a comment but it deserves its own answer.

Comment: Tried it. It has the same problem as stdlib logging: The documentation is not good, in my opinion. And there are a lot less users, so no Google results for questions. I went back to stdlib logging, and found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507825/where-is-a-complete-example-of-logging-config-dictconfig most helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to have a look at [pysimplelog](http://bachiraoun.github.io/pysimplelog/). It's pure python, very simple to use, pip installable and provides what you need

```
from pysimplelog import Logger
L=Logger()
print L
>>> Logger (Version 0.2.1)
>>> log type  |log name  |level     |std flag  |file flag |
>>> ----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|
>>> debug     |DEBUG     |0.0       |True      |True      |
>>> info      |INFO      |10.0      |True      |True      |
>>> warn      |WARNING   |20.0      |True      |True      |
>>> error     |ERROR     |30.0      |True      |True      |
>>> critical  |CRITICAL  |100.0     |True      |True      |

L.info('I am an info')
>>> 2016-09-26 15:01:17 - logger <INFO> I am an info

L.warn('I am a warning')
>>> 2016-09-26 15:01:17 - logger <WARNING> I am a warning

L.error('I am an error')
>>> 2016-09-26 15:01:17 - logger <ERROR> I am an error
```

and with those parameters, a 'simplelog.log' file will be created and updated automatically for you

Comment: +1 Hey that looks cool! One note however: I would not recommend using logging *outside of a function defintion* before it is known [whether that is safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46356672/).

Answer (score -2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import logging
import logging.handlers
from logging.config import dictConfig

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

DEFAULT_LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
}
def configure_logging(logfile_path):
    """
    Initialize logging defaults for Project.

    :param logfile_path: logfile used to the logfile
    :type logfile_path: string

    This function does:

    - Assign INFO and DEBUG level to logger file handler and console handler

    """
    dictConfig(DEFAULT_LOGGING)

    default_formatter = logging.Formatter(
        "[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)s] [%(name)s] [%(funcName)s():%(lineno)s] [PID:%(process)d TID:%(thread)d] %(message)s",
        "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

    file_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(logfile_path, maxBytes=10485760,backupCount=300, encoding='utf-8')
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    console_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    file_handler.setFormatter(default_formatter)
    console_handler.setFormatter(default_formatter)

    logging.root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logging.root.addHandler(file_handler)
    logging.root.addHandler(console_handler)



[31/10/2015 22:00:33] [DEBUG] [yourmodulename] [yourfunction_name():9] [PID:61314 TID:140735248744448] this is logger infomation from hello module
```

you can config logfile with console and file,I don't think desktop notication is a good idea,you can see the log information from console and logfiles

Comment: This is not an alternative.