# How to see the debug messages included in third-party modules of flask?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I would like to see the debug messages for the libraries/modules that I'm using to be displayed along with the debug messages that are present in my code:

```
app.logger.debug("Print this")
```

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably use [logging.basicConfig](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) but recommended way is to handle loggers individually. Here is example from [official documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/errorhandling/#other-libraries):

```
from logging import getLogger
loggers = [app.logger, getLogger('sqlalchemy'),
           getLogger('otherlibrary')]
for logger in loggers:
    logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

You may be also find interesting this: [How to configure all loggers in an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857284/how-to-configure-all-loggers-in-an-application)