# Root logger in dictconfig

Tags: python, django, logging, sentry

I want to setup a Sentry logger for a Django project. I will define a `sentry` handler and will put that handler in the root logger with `error` level.

According to the documentation of [`logging`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details) module, there a special `root` key:

> `root` - this will be the configuration for the root logger. Processing of the configuration will be as for any logger, except that the `propagate` setting will not be applicable.

At the same time in [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7507842/248296) places a logger with name `''` is used to contain configuration for the root logger.

Does this have the same effect? What is preferable?

```
>>> import logging
>>> logging.getLogger('') is logging.root
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Either way will work, because the logger named `''` is the root logger. Specifying the top-level key `root` makes it clearer what you're doing if you're configuring a lot of loggers - the `''` logger configuration could be lost inside a group of others, whereas the `root` key is adjacent to the `loggers` key and so (in theory) should stand out more.

To reiterate, the key named `root` is a top-level key; it's not under `loggers`.

Comment: This does *not* appear to be correct when defining your logging configuration with the [settings.LOGGING](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) attribute in Django 1.7! I'm logging to a named logger in my views module and the log record is captured if I have defined a logger named `''` in my `LOGGING`, but *not* if I name it `'root'`.
Unfortunately, the Django documentation makes no statement on how to deal with the root logger at all.

Comment: @hheimbuerger It's not named root in the loggers dict, it's parallel to the loggers dict. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details for more information.

Comment: 'root' is not a root logger, '' is the root logger.