# python logging - what does a "root" dict key do?

Tags: python, logging, sentry

I am integrating Sentry into my Django project for logging errors, and the starter [logging config they recommend](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/integrations/django/) starts like this:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'root': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'handlers': ['sentry'],
    },
    ...
}
```

now, I am used to listing my loggers and assigning handlers in the "logging" key like this:

```
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
```

This way I capture output from all loggers (the name `''` captures all) and control my handlers.

But what does putting the `root` key in do to the logging hierarchy? I couldn't find the answer in the python docs.

From what I've seen it just disables all my tuned loggers with the single `sentry` logger. I stop seeing my errors in the console, etc.

However if I ignore the sentry `root` advice and just add the logger over here

```
'loggers': {
    '': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins', 'sentry'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
```

All my three loggers start working together in harmony.

So I don't get the `root` thing. What does it do?

Answer (score 2):

root - this will be the configuration for the root logger. Processing of the configuration will be as for any logger, except that the propagate setting will not be applicable.

[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details)

[some more info also stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258986/root-logger-in-dictconfig)