# Basic logging dictConfig in Python

Tags: python, logging

**NOTE** I'm aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507825/python-complete-example-of-dict-for-logging-config-dictconfig) but that doesn't work for me, I am hoping for a complete, self-contained working example.

I'm trying to replace `logging.basicConfig` with `dictConfig` in Python (2.7)

My understanding is `basicConfig` simply sets up the root logger: so I'm attempting to do the same with the `dictConfig`. That is, set up the root logger with a handler, and then all the loggers in my application will propagate up the root logger.

What's missing from the following snippet? The behaviour is the log file is created, but no output makes it. (I've tried various combos of setting levels, it doesn't appear to help)

```
import logging
log_dict = {
    'loggers': {
        'root': {
            'handlers': ['file_handler']
        }
    },
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file_handler': {
            'filename': 'c:/mylogfile.log',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler'
        }
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(log_dict)
logging.info('THIS IS A TEST')
logging.shutdown()
exit()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python: complete example of dict for logging.config.dictConfig?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507825/python-complete-example-of-dict-for-logging-config-dictconfig)

Comment: Not a duplicate, as the linked ticket is not a complete, self-contained working example, and using the dict in that example doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code works perfectly for me:

```
import logging
import logging.config

log_dict = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'default': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': 'standard',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'file_handler': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'filename': '/tmp/mylogfile.log',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['file_handler'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': True
        },
    }
}
logging.config.dictConfig(log_dict)
logging.info("test")
```

And indeed, it's based on the answer mentioned above

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of things wrong with your posted configuration:

1. A logger with a name of `'root'` is not the root logger. The root logger has a name of `''` and is in general better configured using a `'root'` entry *outside* the `'loggers'` configuration, as described in [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#dictionary-schema-details) part of the logging documentation:

> loggers - the corresponding value will be ...
>
> ...
>
> root - this will be the configuration for the root logger. ...

2. You haven't specified a logging level, so it remains at the default level of `WARNING`, which means that `info()` messages won't get shown.

Comment: While it may be true he has a mistake, I think this misses the point, the question asks for a functional equivalent of [`logging.config.dictConfig(config)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) for [`logging.basicConfig(**kwargs)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig).