# Python TimedRotatingFileHandler with dictConfig

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging, python-logging

I am trying to implement `TimedRotatingFileHandler` with `dictConfig`

Here is the code:

```
LOG_SETTINGS = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'default': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s: %(name)s: #%(lineno)d: %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'default',
            'filename': logfile_name,
            'when': 'midnight',
            'interval': 1,
            'backupCount': 5
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        ' ': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True
        },
    }
}
```

> logfile_name = `$HOME/.local/share/app/file.log`
>
> Loading dictionary with  `logging.config.dictConfig(LOG_SETTINGS)`
>
> Writing to file: `logging.debug("Some text")`

This creates a file named `file.log`, but the file is completely empty. I got no errors/warnings.

I visited [Basic logging dictConfig in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36785002/basic-logging-dictconfig-in-python). File seems quite similar.

Where did I go wrong? Using Python 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
import logging  # there we import logging module
logger = logging.getLogger(' ')  # there we get logger by name from settings
logger.debug('yolo')  # there we test logging with custom message
```

UPDATE:
In my company we use that always:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

with define logger:

```
'loggers': {
    'app.views': {
        'handlers': ['handler_name'],
        'level': os.getenv('ERROR', 'INFO'), # needed level
        'propagate': True,
    },
```

Comment: perhaps help more by explaining what that code does?

Comment: It didn't work.


EDIT: It did. Forgot to change to `logger.debug()` earlier.

Comment: How can I resolve module names? Earlier I did `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`, which worked great.

Comment: Thanks! Everything out fine.