# Python logging issues

Tags: python, logging

The `logclient.py` file look like below

This file implements an `es_logger` class which can extract the
line number and file information of the calling line,
and dispatch the message along with this message to
the server

```
class es_logger:  
    def __init__(self, logname='es_general'):
        rootLogger = logging.getLogger('')
        rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        socketHandler = logging.handlers.SocketHandler('localhost',
                        logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT)
        rootLogger.addHandler(socketHandler)
        self.es_logger = logging.getLogger(logname)

def __display__(self, msg, level='DEBUG'):
    levels=['DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL']
    if not level in levels:
        level = 'DEBUG'
        ##msg = 'Defaulting to DEBUG Level' + msg
    if level == 'DEBUG':
        self.es_logger.debug(msg)
    if level == 'INFO':
        self.es_logger.info(msg)
    if level == 'WARNING':
        self.es_logger.warning(msg)
    if level == 'ERROR':
        self.es_logger.error(msg)
    if level == 'CRITICAL':
        self.es_logger.critical(msg)
    return


def logmsg(self, msg, level='DEBUG'):
    '''
    To be called from the python code.
    '''
    log_time=time.asctime()
    code_pos=inspect.stack()[1][1:3]
    code_file=code_pos[0]
    code_line=code_pos[1]
    msgstr='{0} : {1} : {2} : {3}'.format(log_time, code_file,
                                          code_line, msg)
    self.__display__(msgstr, level)
    return
```

I am not posting my server code since it is not needed I guess here.
So I am using this `logclient.py` in another module i.e `wd_update.py` as follow

```
import logclient
import requests

WDU_DATA = 'http://192.168.0.100/cgi-bin//time'
mylogger=logclient.es_logger()

mylogger.logmsg("Hi")
mylogger.logmsg("Hi cgoma INFO", "INFO")
try:
    r = requests.get(WDU_DATA)
except Exception as err:
    print "Error while reaching endpoint"
```

when I am running `wd_update.py` file I am getting logs as

```
Hi
Hi cgoma INFO
Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.0.100
```

I am expecting only first two lines to get printed but I guess Python requests module also having logging implemented in it because of which log statement `Starting new HTTP connection (1): 192.168.0.100*`from requests module is also getting printed which I don't want. Please let me know how to suppress log messages from Python `request` module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable log messages from the Requests library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library)

Answer (score 0):

seems there already have many answers: [11029717](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029717/how-do-i-disable-log-messages-from-the-requests-library)

```
logging.getLogger('requests').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 0):

You configured the root logger, so it will collect messages from any logger with `propagate = True` - which is the default.

FWIW you should just use `logging.DictConfig()` at your app's top-level and use `logger = logging.getLogger(__name_)` in your code - this way all you have to do is to [properly setup the config dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507825/python-complete-example-of-dict-for-logging-config-dictconfig) and your library code is totally independant from the configuration (which is the point of the logging package).