# How to configure 'dictConfig' properly to use a different logging format?

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I am trying to configure my logger using `dictConfig` to use a different format but it does not seem to be taking effect.  Following is the code that I have (I am also simultaneously trying to suppress the logs from imported modules)-

```py
import logging.config
import requests

logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters':{'standard': { 'format': "[%(asctime)s] [%(levelname)8s] - %(message)s", 'datefmt':"%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S %p"}},
    'handlers': {'default': {'level': 'DEBUG', 'formatter': 'standard', 'class': 'logging.StreamHandler', 'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'}},
    'loggers':{'__main__': {'handlers': ['default'], 'level': 'DEBUG', 'propagate': False }}
})

req = requests.get('https://www.google.com')

logging.debug("Only thing that should be printed")
```

**Output** -

```
DEBUG:root:Only thing that should be printed
```

**Expected Output** -

```
[2020-04-04 22:46:24,866] [   DEBUG] - Only thing that should be printed
```

I learnt how to use `dictConfig` from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507825/where-is-a-complete-example-of-logging-config-dictconfig).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the post post that you've mentioned, you will see that you forget a line :)

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

log.debug("Only thing that should be printed")
```

The logger hierarchy must be defined explicitly in the logger name, using dot-notation.

When using the `__name__` :

> This means that logger names track the package/module hierarchy, and
>   it’s intuitively obvious where events are logged just from the logger
>   name.

For more explanations, the docs are pretty [complete](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html).