# How to avoid root handler being called from the custom logger in Python?

Tags: python, logging

I have a basic config for the logging module with debug level - now I want to create another logger with error level only. How can I do that?

The problem is that the root handler is called in addition to the error-handler - this is something I want to avoid.

```
import logging
fmt = '%(asctime)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d:%(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s'
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=fmt)

logger = logging.getLogger('Temp')
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger.error('boo')
```

The above code prints boo twice while I expect once only, and I have no idea what to do with this annoying issue...

```
In [4]: logger.error('boo')
boo
2021-04-26 18:54:24,329:<module>:1:ERROR:Temp:boo

In [5]: logger.handlers
Out[5]: [<StreamHandler stderr (ERROR)>]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Some basics about the logging module

- logger: a person who receives the log string, sorts it by a predefined level, then uses his own handler if any to process the log and, by default passes the log to his superior.
- `root` logger: the superior of superiors, does all the things that a normal logger does but doesn't pass the received log to anyone else.
- `handler`: a private contractor of a logger, who actually does anything with the log, eg. formats the log, writes it to a file or `stdout`, or sends it through tcp/udp.
- `formatter`: a theme, a design that the `handler` applies to the log.
- `basicConfig`: a shortcut way to config the `root` logger. This is useful when you want him to do all the job and all his lower rank loggers would just pass the log to him.
  With no argument, `basicConfig` sets  `root` logger's level to `WARNING` and add a `StreamHandler` that output the log to `stderr`.

### What you did

1. You created a `format` and used a shortcut `basicConfig` to config the `root` logger. You want the root logger to do all the actual logging things
2. You created a new low-rank logger `Temp`
3. You want it to accept logs with only `ERROR` level and above.
4. You created another `StreamHandler`. Which output to `stdout` by default.
5. You want it to handle only `ERROR` level and above
6. Oh, you assigned it to `Temp` logger, which made `5.` redundant since the level is set in `3.` 
   Oh wait, thought you just want the `root` logger to do the job since `1.`!
7. You logged an `ERROR` with your logger.

### What happened

Your `Temp` logger accepted a string `boo` at `ERROR` level. Then told its handler to process the string. Since this handler didn't have any `formatter` assigned to it, it outputted the string as-is to `stdout`: `boo`
After that, `Temp` logger passed the string `boo` to his superior, the `root` logger.

The `root` logger accepted the log since the log level is `ERROR` > `WARNING`.
The `root` logger then told its handler to process the string `boo`.
This handler applies the format string to `boo`. Added timestamp, added location, added the name of logger that passed the log, etc.
Finally it outputted the result to `stderr`: `2021-04-26 18:54:24,329:<module>:1:ERROR:Temp:boo`

### Make it right

Since your code does exactly what you tell it to do, you have to tell it as much detail as possible.

- Only use `basicConfig` when you are lazy. By removing `basicConfig` line, your problem solved.
- Use `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` so that the logger has the name of the module. Looking at the log and know exactly which `import path` that it came from.
- Decide if a logger should keep the log on its own or pass it up the chain with the `propagate` property. In your case, `logger.propagate = False` also solves the problem.
- Use a [dictConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507825/where-is-a-complete-example-of-logging-config-dictconfig) file so you don't get messed with the config code.
- In practice, you should not add handlers to your logger, and just let the logger pass the log all the way to the `root` and let the root do the actual logging. Why?

  - Someone else uses your code as a module, can control the logging. For example, not output to stdout but to tcp/udp, output with a different format, etc.
  - You can turn off the logging from a specific logger entirely, by `propagating=False`.
  - You know exactly all the handlers and formatters in the code if you only added them to the `root` logger. You have centralized control over the logging.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer.

Comment: `'__name__'` is a typo, right? Should be `__name__`?

Answer (score 0):

You could also just set the Logger "[propogate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate)" property to True.

Comment: Please post descriptive answer how to use `propogate` property.